# Suppose $G$ is an Abelian group then possible orders of $ab$ where $a,b\in G$ and are disjoint order elements.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups

*Kindly vet my attempt.*

First of all, group is Abelian, so can be, at best a subgroup of $S_n, n\in \mathbb{N}$, say a cyclic group $\mathbb{Z_n}$ or product of disjoint cycles of such type.

Let $G$ be cyclic group of $n$ elements, and that also implies additive operation.Hence, $C_n\cong \mathbb {Z_n}.$

Next, let the two elements of disjoint orders be $|a|=x, |b|=y.$

An element $a$ with $|a|= x$ will have disjoint cycles as of lengths:

Say, $a= \mathbb{Z}_{x}, b= \mathbb{Z}_{y}.$

The abelian group forbids dihedral groups too, but can be a cyclic subgroup of $D_n$, for suitable natural $n$.

Wlog, $x\gt y.$

So, $|G|\ge x$, i.e. number of elements in the group is at least $x$.

Need ascertain the order of the set formed by product of two elements.

As order of one element is lesser than the other, so at least one of them is not a generator of the group $G$.

Need find the criteria to find order of product of cycles in the two elements.

Such example based on product of disjoint or single cycle, can be expected in symmetric groups , say take some abelian subgroup of $n=6, |S_6|= 6.5.4.3.2.1= 30.24= 720$.

Second question concerns how to interpret elements of group product, represented as tuples in Cartesian product.

Should such tuples(set of elements, one from each group in product)  be taken as pair of generators, if all elements in a tuple are generators?

Else, if not generators (either /both of them), then how to interpret?

Comment: What does "are disjoint order elements" mean?

Comment: @fitzcarraldo Not having the same order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theorem** Suppose $G$ is an abelian group, $x,y \in G$, and the orders of $x$ and $y$ are finite. Then $|xy|$ is also finite and is a divisor $\operatorname{lcm}(|x|,|y|)$.

**Proof** Let $m = \operatorname{lcm}(|x|,|y|)$. Then $|x|$ and $|y|$ are both divisors of $m$, so $x^m = e$ and $y^m = e$. Since $G$ is abelian, $(xy)^m = x^my^m = ee = e$, so $|xy|$ must be a divisor of $m$.

The obvious way to apply this theorem to the problem is to let $x = a$ and $y = b$, and deduce that $|ab|$ is a divisor of $\operatorname{lcm}(60,36) = 180$.

However, we could also take $x = a^{-1}$ and $y = ab$, so that $xy = b$, and the theorem tells us that $36$ is a divisor $\operatorname{lcm}(60, |ab|)$. An integer is divisible by $36$ if, and only if, it is divisible by both $4$ and $9$. Since $60$ is divisible by $4$ but not $9$, we must have that $|ab|$ is divisible by $9$.

Similarly, we could choose $x = ab$ and $y = b^{-1}$, so that $xy = a$, and find that $60$ is a divisor $\operatorname{lcm}(|ab|,36)$. An integer is divisible by $60$ if, and only if, it is divisible by both $12$ and $5$. Since $36$ is divisible by $12$ but not $5$, we must have that $|ab|$ is divisible by $5$.

Therefore we can deduce that $|ab|$ is a divisor of $180$ and is divisible by $45$, so can only be $45$, $90$, or $180$.

In order to show these three orders are possible, in $C_{180}$ (a cyclic group of order $180$) choose three elements, $s$, $t$ and $u$, such that $|s| = 4$, $|t| = 15$ and $|u| = 9$.

If $a = s^{-1}t$ and $b = su$, then $|a| = 60$, $|b| = 36$, and $|ab| = |tu| = 45$.

If $a = st$ and $b = su$, then $|a| = 60$, $|b| = 36$, and $|ab| = |s^2tu| = 90$.

There is no example where the product has order $180$ in $C_{180}$, so let $C_4$ be a cyclic group of order $4$ generated by $v$, and in $C_{180} \times C_4$ let $a = (t,v)$ and $b = (su,1)$. Then $|a| = 60$, $|b| = 36$ and $|ab| = |(stu,v)| = 180$.

Comment: What is the answer, $|ab|=45, 90, 180$ ? Also, is there use of abelian property made?

Comment: @jiten Yes, those are the three possible values of $|ab|$. The theorem which I stated and used (but didn't prove) definitely needs the assumption that $G$ is abelian. In a non-abelian group, knowing the orders of $a$ and $b$ doesn't tell you much about the order of $ab$, e.g. in the dihedral group of $2n$ there are pairs of elements of order $2$ such that their product has order $n$.

Comment: Thanks, but then which property of abelian groups that refers to? Don't know how just $ab= ba$ helps, where $a,b\in G.$ Request link, if possible.

Comment: The hint that wasn't understood till now, is stated below. Kindly elaborate the altered way given below.: So, need satisfy both the necessary condition that the element $ab$ has order dividing $|\langle a, b \rangle|$, as well as the condition for sufficiency? The sufficient part is to check that all divisors are in $ab$. (Hope that means: Say, $3$ cannot be  $|ab|$. ) Another slight altered way to define is since want to find all possible orders of $ab$ then we want to find all possible $k$ that satisfy below two conditions:
(1) $(ab)^k = e,$ 
(2) there is no smaller $k$ s.t. $(ab)^k = e$.

Comment: @jiten I added a proof of the theorem, where $G$ being abelian is needed for $(xy)^m =  x^my^m$. I don't really understand what you are saying about the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Your $a$ and $b$ as groups is wrong; instead, they are *elements* of $G$.

Here is a hint:

Since $G$ is abelian, we have for all $x,y\in G$, that

$$
(xy)^m=x^my^m$$

for any $m\in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: So, $ab$ (in your answer: $xy$) is just a composition of elements $a,b \in G.$

Comment: Yes, @jiten. Think about what this says about the order of $xy$.

Comment: LCM is obvious choice, but for disjoint cycles' product. Here, should be a possibility, as elements can be some cycle or product of disjoint cycles? But, a trap here is, were the two elements having no cycle in common?

Comment: Also, any significance of abelian groups, to the problem, not visible to me still.

Comment: The order of $ab$ in a nonabelian group acts pathologically; for example, @jiten, in the group $$\langle a,b\mid a^2, b^3\rangle,$$ the order of $ab$ is infinite, whereas $|a|=2$ and $|b|=3$.

Comment: Request interpretation of word: " pathologically" in context of your comment. Seems, to mean : goes to infinity.

Comment: It just means that it acts strangely, @jiten.

Comment: Why in group with elements $\langle a,\, b\,\mid \, a^2, b^3\rangle$ have $|a|=2, |b|=3$? Please state the group members, including trivial elements. It is not a cyclic group, as elements $a,b$ seem to have no relation among them.

Comment: It holds by definition of a [group presentation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group), @jiten.

Answer (score 2):

Two tools:

- First, since $a,b$ commute, we have $$(ab)^n=\underbrace{ab\cdot ab\cdots ab}_{\text {n-times}}=a^nb^n$$

So $(ab)^{180}=a^{180}b^{180}=1$.

- Next whenever $g^n=e$, we have $\mid g\mid \mid n$.

Proof:  Let $l=\mid g\mid $.  Write $n=ql+r$, with $0\le r\lt l$.  Then $e=g^n=g^{ql+r}=g^{ql}g^r=eg^r=g^r\implies r=0$, because of minimality of the $l\square $

So $\lvert ab\rvert \mid180$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137919/discussion-on-answer-by-cpc-suppose-g-is-an-abelian-group-and-a-b-in-g-with).

Comment: That is wrong too, tried: $2,3,4,5,6,9,10,12, 15,18,20, 30, 36, 45, 60, 90$ all together.